# How to Stop a function in JavaScript in a sync function?

Tags: javascript, timeout, jspdf

Everyone this I am using this code to print the pdf in landscape mode, printing out two data set each side, this thing is working perfectly but now I thinking of Using a Stop Button which can stop this process.

I am stuck on It so please give some suggestions about it.

Thanks in advance and this is my first-time I'm posting a question on this platform.

```
function timer(ms) {
                return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
            }

            async function load() { // wrap the loop into an async function for this to work
                for (i = 0; i < sCustID.length; i++) {
                    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                    document.getElementById("pdfhead").innerHTML = qrtype;
                    document.getElementById("QRCODEID").innerHTML = sCustID[i];
                    document.getElementById("NAME").innerHTML = sName[i];
                    qrinput[i] = sCustID[i] + "," + sName[i] + "," + sType[i];
                    generateQRCode(qrinput[i]);
                    document.getElementById("printed").innerHTML = i;
                    document.getElementById("pdfhead2").innerHTML = qrtype;
                    document.getElementById("QRCODEID2").innerHTML = sCustID[i + 1];
                    document.getElementById("NAME2").innerHTML = sName[i+1];
                    qrinput[i+1] = sCustID[i+1] + "," + sName[i+1] + "," + sType[i+1];
                    generateSecQRCode(qrinput[i + 1]);
                    document.getElementById("printed").innerHTML = i + 1;
                    PdfFDesignModal.style.display = "block";
                    TimerModal1.style.display = "block";
                    width = ((i+1) * 100) / totalprint1;
                    elem.style.width = width + '%';
                    i = i + 1;
                    savePdf(sCustID[i + 1]);
                    if (i  == sCustID.length) {
                        alert("All QRCODE Printed");
                        PdfFDesignModal.style.display = "none";
                        TimerModal1.style.display = "none";
                    }
                    await timer(1500); // then the created Promise can be awaited
                }
            }
            load();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a button with a listener that calls a function to set a global variable. Then test that variable as part of the conditional test in the for loop.

This will work because of the async nature of the for loop. The call to `stopPrint()` will have an opportunity to interrupt the process

```js
let stop = false;
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', stopPrint);

function timer(ms) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}

async function load() { 
  for (i = 0; i < 10 && !stop; i++) {
    // do PDF work here
    console.log(i);
    await timer(1500); 
  }
}
load();

function stopPrint(){
  stop = true;
}
```

```html
<button id='stop'>Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a custom promise class, the code might look like this one [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-darkness-4ohwu?file=/src/index.js)

```
import CPromise from "c-promise2";

async function yourAsyncTask(i) {
  //some async code here
  console.log(`Task [${i}]`);
  return 123;
}

function load() {
  return CPromise.from(function* () {
    this.innerWeight(20); // for progress capturing, can be omitted
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      yield yourAsyncTask(i); //use yield with promises instead of await here
      yield CPromise.delay(1000); // I don't know why you need a delay
    }
  });
}

const cancelablePromise = load()
  .progress((value) => console.log(`Progress: ${value * 100}%`)) // just for fun let's capture progress
  .then(
    () => console.log("Done"),
    (err) => console.log(`Fail: ${err}`)
  );

setTimeout(() => {
  cancelablePromise.cancel(); // abort async sequence
}, 3500);
```

Console output:

```
Task [0] 
Progress: 5%
Progress: 10%
Task [1] 
Progress: 15%
Progress: 20%
Task [2] 
Progress: 25%
Progress: 30%
Task [3] 
Progress: 35%
Fail: CanceledError: canceled
```